# Linux shell script syntax error on exec command

Tags: linux, shell

I added the following command near the top of my shell script in order to record the script output to a file. This works with no problem when I run the script as my user, jsmith, however when the script is run as root in a crontab, I receive an error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token:

exec &> >(tee $LOG_PATH$TIMESTAMP.log)
```

I do have both $LOG_PATH and $TIMESTAMP correctly defined above the command as:

```
LOG_PATH="/home/jsmith/script/logs/"
TIMESTAMP="$(date -d "today" +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")"
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, Linux feature multiple shells (sh, csh, dash, bash, etc.) which have subtle syntax differences. It is possible that you tested your script with bash, whereas crontabs are executed with dash.

I suggest you the following:

1. check what shell your script requires (looks at the first line)
2. tell cron to use that shell, i.e., set `SHELL=/bin/my_shell` at the beginning of your crontab (see the [manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205) for details).

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. My script requires bash (#!/bin/bash)